# How to add textfield values in list in object form in flutter

Tags: javascript, list, flutter

I have two textfields and i want to add them in list in object form like this

```
{"color":red,"size":L},{"color":blue,"size":S}
```

here is my code

i created this list

```
List<dynamic> _colorList = [];
```

and using it in a button like this

```
 _colorList.add({"color": currentColor, "size": size.text});
```

and i need to remove the items from list too so unable to use `Map<String, Object>`

Error:

```
The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

please help how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `Map<String, dynamic>` and write a custom delete function.

```
void main() {
  
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _colorList = [];
  
  void  deleteByColorName (String colorName)  {
    _colorList.removeWhere((element) {
    return  element["color"] == colorName;
    });
  }
  
  _colorList.add({"color": "colorA", "size": 1});
  _colorList.add({"color": "colorB", "size": 1});
  
  deleteByColorName("colorA");
  
  print(_colorList);
}
```